# Grails 2.4 application as Spring cloud microservice

Tags: spring-boot, grails, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

We want to integrate legacy grails 2.4 and java7 application to our microservices infrastructure. We use spring cloud netflix, Camden.SR4 release and java8 in microservices setup. We use zuul, eureka, config service.

I know that with grails 3 this task is relatively easy, but currently we cant do that.

The biggest question is how can I register grails 2.4 app in Eureka.

Also, we don't want to use sidecar at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud requires Spring Boot. There's nothing keeping you from using the netflix eureka libraries directly.

https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-examples/src/main/java/com/netflix/eureka/ExampleEurekaClient.java

Comment: We've created new spring boot microservice to reuse things we made for other services. Thank you.